# Loading some records to tableview - pull down to refresh

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In a tableview we usually load like a few records (example: 10 records), and then if the user wants more he goes and clicks on the next button, where we load another 10 records.

Instead of clicking on a button to load the next 10 records, i want the user to push down the last record and then load another 10 records.  Look at the [pull To Refresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) project. In this the user will have to hold/pull the first record for awhile to refresh the page. In a similar manner, i want the user to hold/pull the last record to load another 10 records.

Is this possible? and how could i modify the code to do this ?

Important facts:

1.) the arrow image should always point to the last record.
2.) When the user holds the image down, then another 10 records should load, and the arrow image should now be on the 21st record (the last record).

How can i do this programatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like strange way to refresh, but why not :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Add a pinch gesture recognizer to the table view.
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer* pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
    [pinchRecognizer release];
```

handle it:

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinchRecognizer {

    /*
     There are different actions to take for the different states of the gesture recognizer.
     * In the Began state, use the pinch location to find the index path of the row with which the pinch is associated, and keep a reference to that in pinchedIndexPath. Then get the current height of that row, and store as the initial pinch height. Finally, update the scale for the pinched row.
     * In the Changed state, update the scale for the pinched row (identified by pinchedIndexPath).
     * In the Ended or Canceled state, set the pinchedIndexPath property to nil.
     */

    if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        [self updateForPinchScale:pinchRecognizer.scale atIndexPath:newPinchedIndexPath];
    }
    else {
        if (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            [self updateForPinchScale:pinchRecognizer.scale atIndexPath:self.pinchedIndexPath];
        }
        else if ((pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) || (pinchRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)) {
            self.pinchedIndexPath = nil;
        }
    }
}


-(void)updateForPinchScale:(CGFloat)scale atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    if (indexPath && (indexPath.section != NSNotFound) && (indexPath.row != NSNotFound)) {
         // make update here if indexpath == last index path
         /* 
         Switch off animations during the row height resize, otherwise there is a lag before the user's action is seen.
         */
        BOOL animationsEnabled = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
               // do any changes like inform user about download here
            [self.tableView endUpdates];


        [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:animationsEnabled];
    }
}
```

and vu a la

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will apple approve this

Comment: sure, it's from already approved application. please confirm answer as well.

Comment: Can you tell me what is `self.pinchedIndexPath`, How do i define it in the `.h` file

Comment: sure it's @property (nonatomic, retain) NSIndexPath* pinchedIndexPath;